# How to add a validation on delta table column dynamically?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, delta-live-tables

I'm working on a transformation and stuck with a common problem. Any assist is well appreciated.

Scenario:
Step-1: Reading from a delta table.

```
+--------+------------------+
| emp_id |     str          |
+--------+------------------+
|   1    | name=qwerty.     |
|   2    | age=22           | 
|   3    | job=googling     | 
|   4    | dob=12-Jan-2001  | 
|   5    | weight=62.7.     | 
+--------+------------------+
```

Step-2: I'm refining the data and outputting it into another delta table dynamically (No predefined schema). Let's say I'm adding null if the column name is not found.

```
+--------+--------+------+----------+-------------+--------+
| emp_id |  name  |  age |    job   |     dob     | weight |
+--------+--------+------+----------+-------------+--------+
|   1    | qwerty | null |   null   |     null    |  null  |
|   2    |  null  |  22  |   null   |     null    |  null  | 
|   3    |  null  | null | googling |     null    |  null  | 
|   4    |  null  | null |   null   | 12-Jan-2001 |  null  | 
|   5    |  null  | null |   null   |     null    |  62.7  | 
+--------+--------+------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

Is there a way to apply validation in step-2 based on the column name? I'm splitting it by = while deriving the above table. Or do I have to do validation in step-3 while working on the new df?

Second question: Is there a way to achieve the following table?

```
+--------+--------+------+----------+-------------+--------+---------------------+
| emp_id |  name  |  age |    job   |     dob     | weight | missing_attributes  |
+--------+--------+------+----------+-------------+--------+---------------------+
|   1    | qwerty | null |   null   |     null    |  null  | age,job,dob,weight  |
|   2    |  null  |  22  |   null   |     null    |  null  | name,job,dob,weight | 
|   3    |  null  | null | googling |     null    |  null  | name,age,dob,weight |
|   4    |  null  | null |   null   | 12-Jan-2001 |  null  | name,age,job,weight |
|   5    |  null  | null |   null   |     null    |  62.7  | name,age,job,dob    |
+--------+--------+------+----------+-------------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: you can use constraints for the same kind of validation and similary for your second questions : Case statement would help to achieve the same.

Comment: This won't work if I'm creating the table dynamically because I won't be defining any schema.